# concatenate values from two numeric columns + add extra 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Query I like to get concatenated data like below format especially when Val3 has value less than 5 digit extra 0 needs to be added between Val1 and Val2.

```
Val1  VAL2   Val3
===================
3    22       30022
33   22       33022
33   222      33222
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you show the output you want ?

Comment: By that pattern `30 22` and `3 22` will both end up as `30022`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2012+ you can do this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (VAL1 INT, VAL2 INT);
INSERT @table
VALUES (3 , 22 ),(33, 22 ),(33, 222);

SELECT CONCAT(t.VAL1,REPLICATE(0,5-(LEN(t.VAL1)+LEN(t.VAL2))),t.VAL2)
FROM @table t;
```

Comment: Yes i am on SQL 2012. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using arithmetic:

```
select convert(char(5), val1 * power(10, 5-len(val1)) + val2)
from (VALUES(3, 22), (33, 22), (33, 222)) v(val1, val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably better ways to do this, but assuming they all have 5 numbers at the end.

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (VAL1 INT, VAL2 INT, VAL3 INT)
insert into @TEMP(VAL1, VAL2)
VALUES(3,22)
,(33,22)
,(33,222)

UPDATE @TEMP
SET VAL3 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),VAL1) + LEFT('00000',5 - LEN(Val1)-Len(Val2)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),VAL2)

Select * 
from @TEMP
```

Comment: Thank you Holmes for the quick reply. Yes need to have 5 digits and if value doesn't have 5 digit need to have extra 0 as i explained.

Comment: @AnkitShah if you could mark someone's answer correct, in case someone else comes with the same question.

Comment: Not sure but i am trying to do multiple mark as answer but looks like it allows only one?

Comment: @AnkitShah yep, you can pick the one that works best for you or you see first, doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test since I don't have an sql server instance but basically:

1. Get the values in the `val1` column and pad right with `0` as necessary. If you don't know the maximum number of digits in this column ahead of time then you have to get it by way of another query (get max int val, convert to varchar, get its length).

   ```
   Left(Cast(val1 As varchar(2)) + '00', 2)
   ```

Assuming max 2 digits, get a varchar with the left expression inside brackets like `300` then take the left `2` digits, leaving you with `30`.

2. Do the same thing the other way around (left pad) for the values in `val2`.

   ```
   Right('000' + Cast(val2 As varchar(3)), 3)
   ```

Assuming max 3 digits on the other column (`val2`), get a varchar like `00022` and take the right 3 digits, leaving you with `022`.

3. Unite (1) and (2) in a new calculated column, `val3`.

So your calculated column `val3` could look something like

```
    Left(Cast(val1 As varchar(2)) + '00', 2) + Right('000' + Cast(val2 As varchar(3)), 3)
```

And your query therefore

```
select 
    val1, 
    val2,
    Left(Cast(val1 As varchar(2)) + '00', 2) + Right('000' + Cast(val2 As varchar(3)), 3)
from wherever ...
```

See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e54fa05-f021-48e0-8b98-40b62eaeefed/how-to-pad-left-and-right-in-sql-select-statement?forum=transactsql) for example documentation regarding padding.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similiar to some of the other answers, I think.

This would use a simple `LEN` verification to add a specific number of zeroes in the middle, based on the size of the combination of the two column's lenth.

SETUP:

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (VAL1 VARCHAR(5), VAL2 VARCHAR(5), VAL3 VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @TEMP(VAL1, VAL2)
VALUES(3,22)
,(33,22)
,(31,222)
,(32,222)
,(33,222)
,(34,222)
,(35,222)
,(36,222)
,(1,22)
,(0,2)
,(1,2345)
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT VAL1,
    VAL2,
    RIGHT(
        VAL1 + RIGHT(
            '00000', 5 - (LEN(VAL1) + LEN(VAL2))
            ) + VAL2, 5
        ) AS VAL3
FROM @TEMP
```

OUTPUT:

```
+------+------+-------+
| VAL1 | VAL2 | VAL3  |
+------+------+-------+
|    3 |   22 | 30022 |
|   33 |   22 | 33022 |
|   31 |  222 | 31222 |
|   32 |  222 | 32222 |
|   33 |  222 | 33222 |
|   34 |  222 | 34222 |
|   35 |  222 | 35222 |
|   36 |  222 | 36222 |
|    1 |   22 | 10022 |
|    0 |    2 | 00002 |
|    1 | 2345 | 12345 |
+------+------+-------+
```